# Spock: how do I pass different instances to where clause and make invocations count work?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

I want to write 2 test cases for my class:

1. test with normal method invocation
2. test with method invocation which throws RuntimeException

For this I have created the following test. But unfortunately it doesn't work: it ends with "Too few invocations", zero instead of one.

Why?

Code:

```
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class SimpleSpockTest extends Specification {

    interface Simple {
        void run();
    }

    @Shared
    Simple good = Mock(Simple)

    @Shared
    Simple bad = Mock(Simple)

    def "test invocations"() {
        setup:
        bad.run() >> { throw new RuntimeException() }
        when:
        instance.run()
        then:
        invocations * instance.run()
        where:
        instance | invocations
        good     | 1
        bad      | 1

    }

}
```

PS
Also I would like to move "shared" instances to fixture "setup" but I cannot: it fails with saying that class SimpleSpockTest doesn't have property "good" or "bad".

Comment: It seems that this test doesn't make sense at all. What are you trying to achieve? What is your scenario?

Comment: Opal, this is just a simplified example. In real test I want to ensure that 1) exceptions thown by run method are registered correctly (thats why I need mock which throws exceptions, I can count exception handler invocations then) 2) run method is called proper number of times. This test is a simplified example, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Mock objects won't behave the way you want as `@Shared` fields. From Spock's documentation on [Interaction Based Testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_scope_of_interactions):

> Interactions are always scoped to a particular feature method. Hence they cannot be declared in a static method, `setupSpec` method, or `cleanupSpec` method. Likewise, mock objects should not be stored in static or `@Shared` fields.

In other words, you have to define mocks inside of the feature method itself.

You mentioned that the provided example above is simplified, but if possible, you'll have to do something like the following:

```
def "test invocations"() {
    setup:
    Simple good = Mock(Simple)
    Simple bad = Mock(Simple)
    bad.run() >> { throw new RuntimeException() }

    when:
    good.run()
    bad.run()

    then:
    1 * good.run()
    1 * bad.run()
}
```